# How to click out of Combobox?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, combobox, userform

I have a combobox with the properties `MatchEntry 1-fmMatchEntryComplete`and `MatchRequired True`.

I need it true to prevent any invalid entry in the combobox. I dont want to make this a `Style 2-fmStyleDropDownList` but rather keep it a `Style 0-fmStyleDropDownCombo` because I have about 1000 items to choose from.

This setup works, except if you accidentally click in the combobox, and try to click out of it. You keep getting

> Invalid Property Value

Is there anyway I could code the invalid entries so I don't have to assign the property to `True`?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out if anyone has this problem in the future. All I did was keep the properties above, and add this code to my userform for the combobox1.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
  If Me.ComboBox1.Value = "" Then
        'Match not required if zero lenght string
        Me.ComboBox1.MatchRequired = False
    Else
        'Match is required if other than zero length string
        Me.ComboBox1.MatchRequired = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the combo `LostFocus` event. It will check if the value matches one of the combo entries, send a message in case of not, and delete the combo value. Or it can do something else, if my suggestion is not good enough:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_LostFocus()
    If ComboBox1.Value = "" Then Exit Sub
    Dim cbVal As Variant, boolFound As Boolean, i As Long
    cbVal = ComboBox1.Value
    For i = 0 To ComboBox1.ListCount - 1
        If cbVal = ComboBox1.list(i) Then boolFound = True: Exit For
    Next i
    If Not boolFound Then _
        MsgBox "The value """ & cbVal & """ does not exist between the combo items" & vbCrLf & _
                    "It will be deleted", vbInformation, "Illegal entry": ComboBox1.Value = ""
End Sub
```

`MatchRequired` should remain `False` (default)...

Comment: OP refers to Userform controls only (afaik without LostFocus event)?

Comment: @T.M. Not easy to understand only reading the OP question...